# How to follow up TRX suspension training workout?

Tags: workout, cardio

I'm in a TRX suspension class at my gym three days a week that lasts for only 25 min, although they work us pretty hard. I don't really feel like lifting weights after I finish. I usually have the energy for more cardiovascular exercise. What should I do afterward?

I can use the stationary bicycle, elliptical cross-trainer, simply walk, stretch, do a yoga routine, or just go to work (on the other side of a big hill) and eat sooner. My priorities are avoiding and preventing injury, gaining muscle, cardiovascular health, and fat loss, in that order.

I've been getting on the bike for 10 min and then the cross-trainer for 10 min, and that seems to work fine, but I wonder if something else would be a better idea. I have little experience with the cross-trainer too, so I'm not sure how I should set the resistance and what pace I should aim for.

Answer (score 2):

Given your priorities (avoiding injuries as no 1) and your current work out plan, I would go for the yoga routine. Done in the right way, it will give additional awarness of your body that will help in everyday situations. The other options you gave seem to be more of cardio.

To get more variation in your work outs, you could consider to do weigth lifting instead of TRX at least once a week. Variation is good for long term motivation and also reduces the chance for injuries.

Answer (score -1):

I have to admit, 25 min 3 days a week is only going to improve you as far as it can since you using your own weight as a tool to strengthen up.
You need to dedicate yourself more time if you want to tone up. Try 30 min workout on other days of the week and just do weights. Im not sure what muscles you want to tone up.Lets guess arms. Try getting yourself some wrist and ankle weights (weights you can strap to the ankle or wrist, they come between 1kg - 2kg a strap and you can strap more on as you go) and do your arm curls while walking the tredmill and cycling. If you dont have time to train at the gym, use a bag of rice as a weight and do a few shoulder raises, tricep kickback, tricep press.

Good luck